# Multiple languages on website from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is it bad idea to hold translation in database and display words translation based on user settings. I imagined something like this:
mysql

```
lang    | greeting
spanish | ola
english | hi
```

#### for example

`$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lang where lang='spanish'");`

and then just echo that value in proper div

Comment: Dont think that's the worst you can do ;). There are loads of approaches to these problems, most CMS systems use their own. Something to research might be `i10n`

Comment: Though is appears to be a straight forward approach I would advise against it. Word-by-word translations never really make sense. Take a look at the `gettext()` & `.po files` stuff instead. This allows much better translations of expressions (as apposed to words), since you can translate things using `printf` sequences. And you can use the transifex service which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, best is maintaining what I call "interface" texts (English "cancel",Spanish "cancelar",...) with .po files (gettext standard)

On the other hand, all texts likely to be editable by the user, they should be stored in database. Per example, if it is a site which needs to publish a description in different languages, and this description needs to be edited/maintained by the user, and not by the programmer, then you should store the translations in database. And yes,somehing like that table you said is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 1 table for your languages

```
id_lang | label
1 | English
2 | Spanish
3 | French
```

And then each your other tables can have a second key id like this for exemple :

```
traduction_table
id | id_lang | value
1 | 1 | Hi
2 | 2 | Ola
3 | 3 | Salut
```

You need tu have primary keys on id and id_lang.
Then you just have to make your SQL requests correctly, like :

```
select * from traduction_table where ID = 1 and id_lang = ??
```

Where ?? is replaced by the user language ofc.

Answer (score 0):

This way you don't need to add columns for extra languages.

```
id | text    | lang  
------------------------  
1  | ola     |spanish  
2  | hi      |english
```